# Alternate meaning of “sleep with” – sharing the same barracks/bunkhouse?

Tags: word-choice, etymology

I am watching the 1943 western *[The Ox-Bow Incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ox-Bow_Incident)* which is set in Nevada territory in 1885. Early in the film, the bartender is discussing some touchy issue and he says,

> They don't like to talk about it except with the men they sleep with.

I have never encountered the term "sleep with" except that it was used either literally or as a euphemism for having sex. I had assumed the euphemism usage is very old. But maybe based on the usage in the film this assumption needs to be revised.

The men were all cattlemen/cowboys who spent time with their co-workers, so the term "sleep with" is a very compact way of expressing how close the relationship between cowboys was–there is zero implication in the film that it meant anything other than that the men were close co-workers. Moreover, in 1943 had the sexual meaning been prevalent, I would guess the writer would have chosen a different expression.

It is also possible (but I doubt it) that while  the term meant in 1943 what it does today, the writers were somehow aware that in 1885 it had the co-worker meaning. If accurate, this is the opposite of anachronism: it is a very deliberate and scholarly attempt to show the cowboys speaking in authentic 19th century fashion.

**Question:**
Is there any indication that the current meaning of to "sleep with" is of a more recent coinage than 1943? Are there any other movies in which it is used without the sexual implication?

One possibility is that this phrase was specifically about cowboys–men who did literally everything together, eating, working and when they were not working they were sleeping which, unlike most jobs, they also did together. So that to "sleep together" would not have been used for any other profession although soldiers/sailors had an almost exactly similar relationship with their fellows.

EDIT: To clarify the actual question, I am asking if the way the term is used in the movie was common at one time since I have never encountered that usage besides in that movie. If it indeed has the non-sexual meaning of close association, can we find that usage elsewhere?

Comment: It's entirely possible that "the men they sleep with" was used, in this scenario, to refer to the men in the same group who share the same tent or room.

Comment: yes, i am sure it meant exactly that but i think it would not be used in, say, a modern western -- i sure never have encountered it besides in ox-bow incident. not sure about book which i read but do not remember.

Comment: The [sex meaning](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sleep) is over 1000 years old. But this asks various things and I'm not really sure what the actual question is.

Comment: It's not necessarily a question of how old the sexual euphemism is, but whether it was in common usage at the time of the release of the film, and in particular among the target audience. For example, the verb to "know" is used in the Bible to denote having sexual intercourse, and is understood in that context but hardly otherwise today. Oscar Wilde's "The Importance of Being Earnest" — a family favourite — contains sexual slang which would only be understood by a small homosexual community. Even if the sexual meaning was known in 1943, the context in the film might make its use unambiguous.

Comment: The use of "to lie with" as a euphemism can be found in the Old Testament. Leviticus Ch 18 & 20. However in this case "to sleep with" certainly meant literally sleeping in the same room, bunk house or tent and nothing more. The Hayes Code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hays_Code was being strictly enforced in 1943 so any mention of homosexuality was taboo.

Comment: It could be sleep as in death: *2. figurative. To lie in death; to be at rest in the grave.* (OED). They don't like to talk about it except when they're dead — that is, not at all. More likely it means *consort with* or *keep company with*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: If you watch the first several minute of the film, free currently on Youtube, you will get a better feel for how the phrase was used -- if you continue to watch, you might well enjoy an enormously good and unusual flick.

Comment: @PeterJennings: as I recommended to someone else, please watch the beginning of the film. Zero indication that the usage has any sexual connotation.

Comment: Right, so it just means "their people" — the people they keep company with; the Portuguese subtitled version translates it as *gente de confianca* — people they trust. It's neither literal (sleeping in tents, etc.) nor innuendo.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: I agree with meaning, just want to know if this usage can be found anywhere besides this film - I guess I have watched scores of westerns and literally 1000+ movies of any genre not to mention read 1000+ books -- and of course spoken to probably more than 1000 people without encountering this non-sexual usage.

Comment: Sleep with dogs, get up with fleas? The company you keep.

Comment: @David — "Carnal knowledge"

Comment: @AndrewLazarus — I know, I know.

Comment: To avoid the ambiguity one might say, "... except with the men they *bunk* with."

Comment: @Jim: I may have heard that "bunk with" phrase before and that of course is not confused with any sexual meaning except jokingly, like introducing one's spouse as the person you "bunk with" - but these cowboys were driving cattle, not working on a ranch, I think, so there would have been no bunks, they would have been sleeping on blankets by a fire.